# PHPExcel can't calculate OFFSET() function with 4 arguments

Tags: phpexcel

I am using PhpExcel 1.8.0 and I have faced with the problem. PhpExcel can't calculate formula OFFSET() with 4 arguments:

> "Price Sheet!A27 -> Program Settings!H2 -> Formula Error: Wrong number
>   of arguments for OFFSET() function: 4 given, either 3 or 5 expected"

But in description of this formula i have found that this argument "width"
is optional:

> "It is the number of columns that you want the returned range to be.
>   If this parameter is omitted, it is assumed to be the width of range."

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: You fix it either by changing the code yourself (that's the beauty of Open Source) and perhaps then submitting a PR to the developers of PHPExcel; or you raise an issue on the [PHPExcel github site](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation.php` and find the entry in the `$PHPExcelFunctions` array for `OFFSET` which looks like:

```
'OFFSET' => array(
    'category' => PHPExcel_Calculation_Function::CATEGORY_LOOKUP_AND_REFERENCE,
    'functionCall' => 'PHPExcel_Calculation_LookupRef::OFFSET',
    'argumentCount' => '3,5',
    'passCellReference' => true,
    'passByReference' => array(true)
),
```

and change the `argumentCount` block to

```
'argumentCount' => '3-5',
```