# Excel functions showing as it is when converting excel to CSV in php

Tags: php, excel, csv

We are converting excel to CSV with every sheet. For example if a excel file has 5 sheets then we are converting 5 CSV file for every sheet.
Its working fine except one thing.
As we know excel sheet has some formulas for calculation like sum, Average etc..., So when we are converting them to CSV file, Then function is showing as it is, Their calculated value is not showing, which we can read as a excel sheet.

This is the function which we are using

```
function write_csv($filename,$definename){

     $dir = "";  
       $file_arr = array();
     array_push($file_arr, $filename);  
    // Make CSV File 
    $list = array();
    foreach($file_arr as $val)
    {
        $arr_data = array();
     // echo $val;

        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($dir . $val);

      //  print_r($objPHPExcel->getSheetNames());exit;
        $loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcel->getSheetNames();
        foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
       // echo $sheetIndex;
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheetIndex);

                $fp = fopen($definename.'_'.$sheetIndex.'.csv', 'a');
        $cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();
      //  print_r($cell_collection);
        foreach($cell_collection as $cell)
        {
            $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getColumn();
            $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getRow();
            $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();
            //header will / should be in row 1 only. of course this can be modified to suit your need.
            // Skip Rows From Top if you have header in Excel then Change 0 to 1
            if($row == 0)
            {
                $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
            }
            else
            {
                $arr_data[$row]['row'] = $row;
                $arr_data[$row][$column] = $data_value;
            }
        }
        $data = $arr_data;
        foreach($data as $val1)
        {
            $num_col = sizeof($val1) - 1;  // get number of columns in Excel 
            break;
        }
        $lwrcol=array();    
        foreach($data as $val2)
        {
            $alphaArr = range('A','Z');
            $colArr = range('A',$alphaArr[$num_col - 1]);

            foreach($colArr as $col)
            {
                $lwrcol[$col] = isset($val2[$col]) ? utf8_decode($val2[$col]) : "";
                fwrite($fp,$lwrcol[$col].",");
            }
            fwrite($fp,"\n");   
        }
       // chmod(getcwd()."/file.csv", 0777);
                fclose($fp);
            }
    }
}
```

Please tell me what we are doing wrong.

Complete Code:

http://pastebin.com/DaRBSpqP

Comment: Do you need it a comma separated CSV? Like a plain text??

Comment: Yes, its ok. If i get it. we need to see where we are doing mistake in our code

Comment: Do the formula's work in the sheet? Do you see "26.5" or "=average(A1:A5)"? Because if it's the latter, then you're problem is with the cell type.

Comment: yes, i have only one sheet. but my problem is client can uplload any type of sheet. i need to handle this type of error.

Comment: We found the example which is showing data, But its converting our whole sheet in to CSV. [link] (http://hayageek.com/convert-xls-to-csv-in-php)

Comment: Why aren't you using PHPExcel's CSV Writer? It comes "built-in" to the library

Comment: And if you absolutely have to "roll your own csv writer" then use `$data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getCalculatedValue();`, not `$data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();`

Comment: Yes. We are using PHPExcel-1.8, But its creating CSV correctly. @MarkBaker

Comment: Yes, we also tried with getClacutedValue, But its showing this error

Comment: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception' with message 'Price Sheet!A27 -> Program Settings!H2 -> Formula Error: Wrong number of arguments for OFFSET() function: 4 given, either 3 or 5 expected' in /var/www/html/investorListPoject/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php:291 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/investorListPoject/index.php(115): PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue() #1 /var/www/html/investorListPoject/index.php(67): write_csv('151103/007_17.x...', '151103/007_17') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/investorListPoject/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 291   @MarkBaker

Comment: Given that the only PHP library that can handle calculations in Excel spreadsheets is PHPExcel (unless you want to use COM, PUNO or the commercial libXL), then the real issue is the implementation of the OFFSET() function

Comment: Yes, but then other libraries doesnt have this issue? like http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader This is the reason why i move to another library

Comment: And which of those other libraries can calculate formulae in Excel sheets?

Comment: yes, above and this one also calculating formulas http://php-drops.blogspot.in/2011/04/read-excel-sheet-xls-file-with-php.html Just the problem its not showing date in these libraries

Comment: The problem with OFFSET() was posted [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365672/phpexcel-cant-calculate-offset-function-with-4-arguments), by another user, barely a week ago; but hasn't been raised as an issue on the github repo yet.... unless an issue is raised on github, then it isn't my highest priority, especially as I've been away for a large part of that week

Comment: But if you see the comments here http://php-drops.blogspot.in/2011/04/read-excel-sheet-xls-file-with-php.html another users also has this problem

Comment: I still don't understand why the homebrew CSV writing either

Comment: Sorry didnt understand. But if i get the data correctly i will write the data using php_excel

Comment: I've posted a fix for the OFFSET() issue to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365672/phpexcel-cant-calculate-offset-function-with-4-arguments/33486265#33486265 - I'll change it on github later

Comment: You should probably also update to PHPExcel 1.8.1 from github as well

Comment: We updated. Sorry but still its not working.